# get name of the app the user chose from app list (android)

Tags: android, onactivityresult

making an android app, i have this intent setup to let the user choose from a list of all apps and it works ok.

```
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);            
            Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
            pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, mainIntent);
            startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 0);
```

i have also added the an onActivityResult() method without writing any code in it. What code do i need in the onActivityResult() method to get the package name of the app the user chose?

(or any other information with which i can launch the chosen app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        ComponentName componentName = data.getComponent();
        final String packageName = componentName.getPackageName();
        final String activityName = componentName.getClassName();
    }
}
```

or you can just startActivity(data); so you can launch which app that user choosed.

Comment: thnx a lot! i've been searching for this fow a whole day with no luck