# get confirmation from the app chosen from the applist (Intent.ACTION_SEND)

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I'm going through the same situation. and In my case, i am getting null data(Intent) due to which the following code is not running

```
if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) 
{
    ComponentName componentName = data.getComponent();
    final String packageName = componentName.getPackageName();
    final String activityName = componentName.getClassName();
}
```

Any solution for this? Because whenever i post a text through any application (Gmail/facebook). The response is sending the message or your message is posted by the application selected by user.

I want to get application name on which the user click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295802/get-name-of-the-app-the-user-chose-from-app-list-android/25028758#25028758

Comment: Which is causing null..

Comment: hie @saleeh93 please read this link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295802/get-name-of-the-app-the-user-chose-from-app-list-android) 'Link'